# Query runs in Access but not C#

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I've got the following Access query:

```
select [Module.ID], [Module.mname], [ModuleMarks.Mark] 
FROM (Student LEFT OUTER JOIN   ModuleMarks ON Student.ID = ModuleMarks.StudentId) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Module ON ModuleMarks.ModuleId = Module.ID where Student.ID = 1;
```

This runs in Access with no problems.

However running the same query through C# with the following code:

```
OleDbConnection dbCon = new OleDbConnection(Properties.Resources.connectionString);
dbCon.Open();
string sqlStudentMarks = "select [Module.ID], [Module.mname], [ModuleMarks.Mark] " +
            "FROM (Student LEFT OUTER JOIN ModuleMarks ON Student.ID =
            ModuleMarks.StudentId) LEFT OUTER JOIN Module ON ModuleMarks.ModuleId =
             Module.ID " + "where Student.ID = " + studentId.ToString() + ";";
Debug.WriteLine(sqlStudentMarks);
OleDbCommand dbCmd = new OleDbCommand(sqlStudentMarks, dbCon);
OleDbDataReader dbReader = dbCmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Fails with error `IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005)`. on the `ExecuteReader` line.

The debug out written from the string is:

```
"select [Module.ID], [Module.mname], [ModuleMarks.Mark] FROM (Student LEFT OUTER JOIN ModuleMarks ON Student.ID = ModuleMarks.StudentId) LEFT OUTER JOIN Module ON ModuleMarks.ModuleId = Module.ID where Student.ID = 1;"
```

I should note I've tried it without the colon and it still provides the same error.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Please post your connection string.

Comment: What are the brackets for around the initial table definition (student and the first left outer join).  I'm not 100% familiar with Access - is this necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is **Module** is a **reserved** word. Change `Module` as `[Module]`.

Do not use reserved words or put the square brackets [] around the field name or table name, ie:

You have used Square bracket with both tablename and column name as [Module.ID] but you should use it as [Module].ID.

Try this

```
select [Module].ID, [Module].mname, [ModuleMarks].Mark 
FROM Student LEFT OUTER JOIN ModuleMarks ON Student.ID = ModuleMarks.StudentId LEFT OUTER JOIN [Module] ON ModuleMarks.ModuleId = [Module].ID where Student.ID = 1;
```

> [Access Reserved words and symbols](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-HA010030643.aspx)

Comment: @lain s- You have used Square bracket with both tablename and column name as [Module.ID] but you should use it  as [Module].ID.I have updated query. Can you check now....

Answer (score 0):

SELECT md.ID, md.mname,mm.Mark FROM   Student s
       LEFT OUTER JOIN ModuleMarks mm
            ON  s.ID = mm.StudentId
       LEFT OUTER JOIN [Module] md
            ON  mm.ModuleId = md.ID
WHERE  s.ID = 1;

Answer (score -1):

Try to use OleDbDataAdapter:

```
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqlStudentMarks, dbCon);
        OleDbCommandBuilder cb = new OleDbCommandBuilder(da);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
```

Thats work nice for me.